# AsyncImageView is not loading images in iOS 9.0 xcode 7+

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, asyncimageview

I am using following code for iOS 8.x.x xcode 6.4 and it is working fine;

```
        AsyncImageView *categoryview = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Cate.frame.size.width, Cate.frame.size.height)];
        categoryview.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURLs objectAtIndex:j]];
        categoryview.showActivityIndicator = YES;
        categoryview.showProgressView = YES;
        [Cate addSubview:categoryview];
```

and if I use the same code in iOS 9.0 xcode 7, it is only showing ActivityIndicator and doesn't load any picture.

I am using this Library: [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

asyncimageview uses NSURLConnections which is depreciated in ios9.